# boolean on local storage doesn't work

Tags: javascript, boolean, local-storage

I have this code.
The purpose of the code is to set the 'source' value in when the user arrive to my website, 
and not to change it if he moves between pages.

The problem is, 
in each page I can see in the console
len = 0;

What should have happen was:

on first page - there should not be a paramater in 'source',
so len should be 0
If I move to another page, 
source should have a value in it, 
so len should not be 0,
but for some reason - 
it keep show me that len = 0;

(In the full script - I check the source where the user arrived, 
Like adwords / organic / direct / refferal,
And put this value in the source variable in LocalStorage.
The problem is, 
When I move to another page, 
It take the refferal of the page and change the source,
and that is not good for me)

What am I doing wrong?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var initsource = localStorage.getItem('source');
        if (initsource == null)
        {
            var len=0;
            localStorage.setItem('source','firstsoure');
        }
        else
        {
            var len = initsource.length;
        }
        console.log('len = %s',len);
</script>
```

Comment: because on every page this script is running

Comment: How come `'firstsoure'` is a boolean?

Comment: I'm not sure but you may want to add initsource == undefined and probably initsource ==""

Comment: Are you sure pages are in the very same domain?

Comment: On the face of it, there's nothing wrong with your code.  You'll need to post some more information about your environment etc.

Comment: Also you code works as expected https://jsfiddle.net/9LtyeL9j/

Comment: yes. this script runs on every page

Comment: yes, of course :)

Comment: because on every page this script is running

Comment: @YanivLevAri this is the reason you are getting console output on every page you visit.